# Separation of concerns between Facelets and JSF backing beans

Tags: jsf, model-view-controller, facelets, separation-of-concerns

This is such a fundamental MVC question I have a feeling the answer is already on SO and I just can't find it. Please forgive me if it's a dupe.

I am reimplementing a big legacy JSP/servlet app in JSF2/Spring3/Facelets. I think in general we want to leave the presentation formatting to the .xhtml and use the backing bean to make the data suitable for display. This makes for a nice separation of concerns even though I believe both are part of the View. However, the legacy app has an attractive table that contains headings on the left and HTML formatted stuff on the right, like links that pop up a dialog (only one row has this). I decided to put all the content in objects that a datatable iterates through and it worked but I found myself putting sort of ugly HTML (for links and such) in the backing bean, and putting ugly conditions in the datatable (e.g. if this is row 0, then use this CSS class). This works but it doesn't feel right. I've very tightly coupled the backing bean to the presentation, but I can't think of a simple way to get around it. Does anyone have any guidelines around how to handle this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just don't put HTML/CSS/JS in Java class, but put it in Facelets file instead. Then everything should go well all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a valid usecase for a JSF Component. A very good guidance is this book: http://jsfatwork.irian.at/book_de/custom_component.html (Free available online)